# Blazor: Change button to spinner while httpClient does GET request

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Using Blazor (server-side), I have a simple button I'd like to change to a spinner like [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/spinners/#buttons) when a search is being performed. I want the UI to temporarily display "Loading..." on the button while this happens.

I'm using an `<InputForm>` tag to render a form with an `<InputSelect>` and an `<InputText>` field. When I click the submit button the form's `OnValidSubmit` fires `HandleSearch()`. I would expect the `ShowLoader` to update the UI element right away but it doesn't until the `GetDataAsync` completes, then it never changes back to a Search button.

I suspect there is a better way to achieve this simple task. Any ideas?

#### Html:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-3">
    @if (ShowLoader)
    {
        <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span>Loading...</span>
    }
    else
    {
        <span>Search</span>
    }
</button>
```

#### Code block:

```
@code {
    public class SearchBox
    {
        [Required]
        public string SearchValue { get; set; }
        public string SearchField { get; set; }
    }

    public SearchBox search = new SearchBox();
    public bool ShowLoader = default;

    protected async Task HandleSearch()
    {
        ShowLoader = true;
        try
        {
            var result = await functionsClient.GetDataAsync<Reservation>(FunctionsClientConstants.ReservationsPath + "?field=" + search.SearchField + "&value=" + search.SearchValue);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
        }                   
        ShowLoader = false;
    }
}
```

#### GetDataAsync method:

```
public async Task<T> GetDataAsync<T>(string path)
{            
    HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.GetAsync(path).Result;

    using HttpContent content = response.Content;
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(await content.ReadAsStringAsync());
}
```

#### Update:

I changed the try/catch block to use a `await Task.Delay(2000)` instead of my GET and the search button behaves as it should. You click the button and it changes to "Loading..." for 2 seconds then changes back.

p.s. I realize there is [a better way to handle async JSON](https://josefottosson.se/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/) but I'm having an issue with my inbound payload causing a deserialization fault at the moment so I'm using Newtonsoft.Json instead. Right now my GET causes a fault but that shouldn't impact the rendering of the UI if I'm catching, should it??

Comment: This code looks OK, "it doesn't until the GetDataAsync completes" should not happen.  Show that functionsClient.GetDataAsync() method, it is doing something wrong.

Comment: The GetDataAsync is crashing due to a JSON deserialization issue I have which is why I added the try/catch. I updated my testing behavior as well as the code block for the GET...

Comment: It won't hurt to put a `StateHasChanged();` before the GetData() call.

Comment: thx for the suggestion. just tried that...no change :(

Comment: Adding `await Task.Delay(1)` before my async GET call worked!

Comment: OK, but the core problem is `response = httpClient.GetAsync(path).Result;`, make that `response = await httpClient.GetAsync(path);`. Always avoid calling `.Result`